# How to close an executable on Python like clicking on exit button

Tags: python, executable, exit, clicking

I will explain my problem :

For an application for my system I would like to know how to close an executable, like clicking on the pushbutton exit in the top rigth, as usual. Context :
From a script python, I would like to run an executable. It is works fine with os.system or subrpocess popen. Moreover, I would like to know when this executable is close, it's works fine with subprocess check output. And my problem : I would like to close the executable that I ran, but for many reasons on my system (the .exe send an snmp messages when it is closed by the button "close" in the top right to an another script, I can't change that), I have to close this executable as if I close manually the executable window.

To do self.p.terminate did'nt works.

Please, if you have any ideas, tell me. Thanks for your answer, Have a good day

My code is below :

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys,string,os
import threading 
import time 

class test():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def lancement(self):
        os.chdir('C:\dossier')
        self.p = subprocess.Popen("C:\dossier\TEST.exe")
        self.id = self.p.pid
        #os.system("C:\dossier\TEST.exe")
        
    def verification(self):
        while True :
            
            self.s = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell = True)
            
            if b"TEST.exe" not in self.s :
                print('Absent')
                
                break
            
            else : 
                print('toujours present')

    def fermeture(self):

        #os.close("C:\dossier\TEST.exe")
        #self.p.terminate()
        os.kill(self.id,signal.SIGTERM)
    def tests(self):
        ouais = threading.Thread(target =self.lancement)
        ouais.start()
        time.sleep(2) 
        testverif = threading.Thread(target = self.verification)
        testverif.start()
        time.sleep(20) 
        self.fermeture()
 
def main():
    testa = test()
    testa.tests()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os` modules for this.

```
os.system("taskkill Test.exe")
```

This would gently Kill the application.

`taskkill` is a cmd command which helps you to Kill process. `os.system()` method execute the command (a string) in a subshell/cmd.

Also check [the taskkill docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) of further parameter if needed.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your quick answer. Your are right, I have to use taskkill. I did'nt know that. However is  os.system("taskill /im Test.exe"). We have to add /im to specifiy the name. Without /im it did'nt works. Thanks a lot !